# Mantle om moving object

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I Implemented mantle mechanics on a static object.How i can do mantle on moving object(UE4 c++)?

I'm trying to move a character according to the position of the moving object but it's unsuccessful.
Please maybe someone did similar mechanics can share code?